# Open/ Close Eclipse project using Ant

Tags: eclipse, ant, project

My application is a dynamic web application which is dependent on 9 different modules with only java source. The source code of the application and the dependent components are maintained in the SVN. So, I thought of doing the following structure in Eclipse.

- I will have a Dynamic Web Project in my eclipse, which is the main project.
- The jar files of the dependent modules are available in Web-project's WEB-INF\lib directory. So, unless I want to see the java source directly, I don't need those module's source code.
- I will create independent java projects for each module, which are by default will be in closed state.
- I will maintain flags whether a project should be open or close in the build.properties file.

When I want to do a full build, I'm expecting the following steps;

1. The ant should check the flag in the properties file and see if the dependent module is required to see the source
2. Open the project
3. Put the java source files in to the src folder
4. Compile the source
5. Prepare a fresh jar
6. Keep the jar in the WEB-INF\lib folder.

I'm able to handle all the remaining tasks except (2) i.e. opening the project using ant.

Is it possible. If so, can anybody suggest a solution?